# How to disable word wrapping in plain text files in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, word-wrap

I need Chrome to display plain text files with long lines that should not be wrapped. But when Chrome displays a plain text file (text/plain) it wraps the lines around. How can I induce it to exhibit Firefox-like behavior (no wrapping, show scrollbars instead)?

I have tried to wrap the text into a  element and it works but takes astonishing amount of time to load, even for relatively short text.

Answer (score 3):

The easier solution for this is to right click and open "View Page Source". In this view the lines are not wrapped by default and "Line Wrap" is an option that can be toggled with a check box at the top of the page.

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking at this too. The closest I've found is to use the command line and launch chrome but forcing to create a custom user style sheet.

Documented here : http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=2393

You can then edit you local style sheet and update the css for pre tags (which is how chrome renders text/plain by default) to remove the "word-wrap: break-word" so the lines are not broken.

Comment: Alas, it looks like adding 

pre {
  white-space: pre !important;
  word-wrap: normal !important;
}

still doesn't let me override the inline style that Chrome puts into the <pre> element that surrounds the file contents. Were you able to override that style?

Answer (score 1):

I just loaded Syntaxtic extension and it works perfectly on my Windows 7. It unwraps the lines automatically whenever a text file is loaded!

Comment: What is Syntaxtic extension? What does it do? Where to find it? Can you add more details?

Answer (score 0):

I hate to suggest an extension for something so simple, but the [Syntaxtic!](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/syntaxtic/cgjalgdhmbpaacnnejmodfinclbdgaci) extension supports this.

It's used to add syntax highlighting and line numbers to text files, so it definitely does more than you want it to, but at least it can disable word wrap.

Comment: I can't get this extension to install for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this on a case-by-case basis with something like [Stylus](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylus/clngdbkpkpeebahjckkjfobafhncgmne).

I just added a rule for the page I cared about that contained:

```
pre { 
    white-space: pre !important; 
}
```